# Jquery Masterpage Can not Change the text for a textbox from client side

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, telerik

Ok this one is one of those that has had me bangin my head against the wall for acouple of hours. It seems very simple, I am using a Masterpage, Telerik controls and telerik RadScriptblock and Jquery. I am trying to change the text of an asp.net textbox in the grid edit form from client side code but it JUST WILL not WORK! I have tried the following with no luck.

```
 Text box: 

 <asp:TextBox  ID="txtNewProduct" runat="server"/>

 // JQuery inside RadScriptBlock
 //Have tried all these but dont work

// $('#txtNewProduct').text('New Product');
//  $('#txtNewProduct').attr('text', 'New Product');
//  $('#txtNewProduct').val('New Product');

//This one gets me the object but it CANT seem to set the text have been trying 
//for hours

//var txtnew = $('[id$=txtProduct]');
//txtnew.text = "New Product";  //This shows the value "New Product" in clienst side 
//but does not change the textbox's text
```

If someone can point out how to do this simple task you might save me and some other poor soul some therapy :) thank you in advance.

Comment: There's an excellent explanation for how client IDs are generated in ASP.net at http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is most likely changed if you are using a master page, check the source code that is generated.

Comment: wow thanks Paul I think i need some sleep, I knew all along the ID was changed but you got me thinking I got the ID by using $('[id$=txtProduct]') and it was some thing God aweful like       ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_PageContent_ProductGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_txtNewProduct and I was able to set the text box's text by doing  $('[id$=txtNewProduct]').val('New Product');

Comment: if you're using the .NET 4.0 Framework you can tell it not to generate IDs by setting the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to `Static` at the Control, Page, or Application level

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Creasey said, check the generated source and then ensure your jQuery library file(s) successfully loaded...if loaded, then use something like Firebug (in Firefox) to test the jQuery. `$('#txtNewProduct').val('New Product')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that was frustrating I hope it helps someone else out as well I was able to change the textbox's text using

```
$('[id$=txtNewProduct]').val('New Product');
```